# Posting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I just finished an intro course to python and am working on a little project. The goal is simply to extract data out of a website. I'm avoiding the use of libraries such as Selenium and Mechanize because I'm trying to learn how the requests library works. Below is my code.

```
s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33SSearchWidget'
data = {'FLAT_TYPE':'03',
        'NME_NEWTOWN':'AMK+++++Ang+Mo+Kio',
        'NME_STREET':'',
        'NUM_BLK_FROM':'',
        'NUM_BLK_TO':'',
        'dteRange':'12',
        'DTE_APPROVAL_FROM':'Dec+2015',
        'DTE_APPROVAL_TO':'Dec+2017+',
        'AMT_RESALE_PRICE_FROM':'',
        'AMT_RESALE_PRICE_TO':'',
        'Process':'continue',
        'null':'null'
        }

userAgent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0','Referer':'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33PReslTrans.jsp'}

page = s.post(url,data=data,headers=userAgent).content
print(page)
s.close()
```

But this seems to give me the code for the form instead. This result doesn't change even if I don't include data, hence I assume the data is not being posted correctly. When inspecting, I see that the page doesn't have query string parameters, but instead has something called 'Form Data'. I'm not sure how to post the parameters to this. Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Comment: use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to see request send by browser when you use page in browser. Maybe it need other headers or hidden fields in form, or cookies, or some fields are filled by different value in different request using cookies or time/timestamp.

Comment: if you use session then you could GET page first to gey cookie (session id) and values in hidden fields which can change value in every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, firstly requests form-encodeds the POST data so you don't need to secondly you need to perform a GET before the POST to set up cookies etc.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33SSearchWidget'

data = {'USER_PROFILE': '2',
        'FLAT_TYPE': '03',
        'NME_NEWTOWN': 'AMK     Ang Mo Kio',
        'NME_STREET': '',
        'NUM_BLK_FROM': '',
        'NUM_BLK_TO': '',
        'dteRange': '12',
        'DTE_APPROVAL_FROM': 'Dec 2015',
        'DTE_APPROVAL_TO': 'Dec 2017',
        'AMT_RESALE_PRICE_FROM': '',
        'AMT_RESALE_PRICE_TO': '',
        'Process': 'continue',
        'null': 'null'
        }

userAgent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0',
             'Referer': 'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BB33RTIS/BB33PReslTrans.jsp'}

s.get(url, headers=userAgent)
page = s.post(url, data=data, headers=userAgent)
# print(page.text)
s.close()


# just to check
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'height': '30'}):
    print (tr.text)
```

Outputs:

```
220
 Ang Mo Kio Ave 1
10 to 12
67.00New Generation
1977
58 years
$280,000.00
Dec 2017


225
 Ang Mo Kio Ave 1
07 to 09
82.00New Generation
1978
59 years
$350,000.00
Dec 2017

...
```

Comment: Oh hey! Thanks. Been trying to do this for the past few days... Just a few things to clarify though, if I use get on the url, it will load the page along with all the cookies and everything as though I'm accessing it through the browser? In which case the session will store these without the need for me to store it in a variable and passing it into the post request? Looks like I still don't fully understand requests. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Yes if you use GET on the URL it will be like you going to the page in a browser, cookies will be set and stored by the requests session object automatically. When you do a POST it is like sending the form, the requests session will pass cookies it has from previous requests  automatically.